# .Net Core Вызов Команд

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

У меня на Линукс машине есть софт который работает через команды (типа wert-qw --f )
Есть необходимость вызывать эти команды программно на .Net Core. Как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/) найден хороший пример

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
public static class ShellHelper
{
    public static string Bash(this string cmd)
    {
        var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
        
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

и вызов

```
var output = "ps aux".Bash();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Также нагуглил данный пример, но немогу через него составные команды (2 и более слов в команде) вызывать они как-то своеобразно обрабатываются. Искал хоть какой-то рабочий код.

Comment: а можете расшифровать, что значит "своеобразно обрабатываются?"

Comment: я когда загоняю обычную команду (к примеру `dir`) - получаю норм ответ, команда `help` - зависает процесс,  когда что-то посложнее (`help cd`) - получаю ошибки связанные с вводом аргументов

Comment: Команда help похоже использует "пейджер". Для таких команд надо либо отключать пейджер либо обрабатывать отдельно (симулировать нажатие стрелок вниз или пробела и считывать ввод постепенно. Для некоторых команд (к примеру far/mc) это может быть весьма нетривиально. В любом случае WaitForExit имеет параметр, который позволит задать период ожидания.